# Why is placing an html5 canvas over a video not covering the video, instead the canvas shows no colored background, video freezes to a single frame

Tags: html, reactjs, canvas, html5-video, styled-components

I hope you could give me a few minutes of your time. I am trying to implement a dark background canvas to cover up a video in its background, the code beneath should be able to do that with fill style and the source over, but for some reason it is not, do you have an Idea of how to solve this?

```
let canvas = useRef(null);
    const size = useWindowSize();
    const { currentTheme } = useGlobalStateContext()

    useEffect(() => {
        let renderingElement = canvas.current;
        let drawingElement = renderingElement.cloneNode();

        let drawingCtx = drawingElement.getContext("2d");
        let renderingCtx = drawingElement.getContext("2d");

        let lastX;
        let lastY;

        let moving = false;

        renderingCtx.globalCompositeOperation = "source-over"
        renderingCtx.fillStyle = currentTheme === "dark" ? "#000000" : "#ffffff";
        renderingCtx.fillRect(0,0, size.width, size.height)
        console.log(renderingCtx)

    }, [])
  return (
    <Banner>
      <Video>
        <video
          height="100%"
          width="100%"
          loop
          autoPlay
          src={require("../../assets/video/video.mp4")}
        />
      </Video>
      <Canvas
        height={size.height}
        width={size.width}
        ref={canvas}
      />
      <BannerTitle variants={container} initial="initial" animate="animate">
        <Headline variants={item}>DIG</Headline>
        <Headline variants={item}>DEEP</Headline>
      </BannerTitle>
    </Banner>
  )
}
```

===============================
i am making use of styled components,

```
import styled from "styled-components"
import { motion } from "framer-motion"

//Banner
export const Banner = styled.div`
  background: ${props => props.theme.background};
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100%;
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 296px;
`
export const Video = styled.div`
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  video {
    object-fit: cover;
  }
`
export const Canvas = styled.canvas`
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  height: 100%;
  display: block;
`
```

This block of code is applying a dark background to the canvas so it can cover up the video behind it
but instead of covering the video up (the screen would be dark and the video will be playing in the background) instead something else shows

This is the image of the final result

[image]

Comment: Apply the `z-index` property to the `canvas` or you could use the `filter` property on the video and set the value to `brightness(0)`. It should paint the whole video black [MDN Filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/filter-function/brightness())

Comment: Hey, if you notice I'm using the globalCompositeOperation set to source-over in my useEffect, which should give me the same effect as z-index being set to a higher property, but for some reason it does not work, hence two effects happen, the canvas isnt being drawn and the video freezes like its an image(instead of playing) @a.mola

Comment: The `globalCompositeOperation` only affects the way no things are drawn onto the canvas, not how it interacts with other elements. Does the video play without the canvas?

Comment: @a.mola, Yes it does, it plays without the canvas being there, but when the canvas is placed over it, the videos ceases to play, instead that image is shown, and it doesnt matter if i added the z-index or not, still doesnt work, brigthness(0) seems to work but it makes the video not show at all. I'd like for the canvas to just cover the video while it continues to play on. but thats not working

Answer (score 0):

Well, the video's `autoplay` wasn't working because of some new security fixes. [Read more](https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes) and you need to have the `muted` attribute on the `HTMLMediaElement`.

I created an event listener on the video so that when it starts playing, it removes the `muted` attribute. I passed the `once` option so the event would be called once.

```js
const canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
const video = document.getElementById('video');
const ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');


video.addEventListener('play', _ => {
  console.log('playing');
  canvas.width = getComputedStyle(video).width.slice(0, -2);
  canvas.height = getComputedStyle(video).height.slice(0, -2);
  ctx.fillRect(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height);
}, { once: true });
```

```css
body {
  position: relative;
  height: 100vh;
  width: 100vw;
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

video {
  width: 75vw;
}

canvas {
  position: absolute;
  top: 50%;
  left: 50%;
  transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}
```

```html
<video id="video" src="http://commondatastorage.googleapis.com/gtv-videos-bucket/sample/ElephantsDream.mp4" muted autoplay controls></video>
<canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
```

Comment: Thanks for this, the video is actually playing once more, the only issue now is that the canvas is not being created or displayed, in the code the canvas is supposed to cover the entire video with either a black or white color depending on the theme of the app, so what we should have is a black background and the video playing behind it(we dont see the video playing behind, but it should, what we see is just a black background), and its almost like the canvas context created do not apply the styles i assigned, and I dont want to use the brightness or the z-index property , thoughts? @a.mola

Comment: I've edited my code, just add the `muted` attribute @Irongatez